# I can't get Atom text editor + leiningen + proto-repl to work (for programming Clojure)

Tags: atom-editor, leiningen, proto-repl

Anything that Atom + proto-repl does involves lein, so I decided to check out lein. 'lein help' works, but attempting 'lein repl' gives the following errors:

```
  gw-mac-pro:~ gr$ lein repl
Could not find artifact proto-repl:proto-repl:jar:1.4.24 in central (https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/)
Could not find artifact proto-repl:proto-repl:jar:1.4.24 in clojars (https://repo.clojars.org/)
This could be due to a typo in :dependencies, file system permissions, or network issues.
If you are behind a proxy, try setting the 'http_proxy' environment variable.
Could not resolve dependencies
```

I get the same set of messages when I attempt to run code from within Atom.

I've searched for hours for any kind of arcana about Atom, lein, or proto-repl, and I'm amazed that searching on 'lein error could not find artifact' continues to find nothing useful.

I'm surprised that no one has encountered this same problem. I'm running on macOS Mojave (10.14.6). Can you help me? Thanks.